# How to decrease the value of a variable that you don't know in advance?

Tags: python, math

I have a function that accepts a parameter. In order for this function to 'converge', this parameter must be lower a bit than its original value.

The problem is that the value of this parameter is unknown in advance. So one time it could be `0.01` and another `0.0000084662`, so I'm unable to know in advance how much to subtract from it.

Is there an easy way to decrease this parameter without knowing its value in advance? It just needs to be decreased a bit. The parameter will always be in the range [0.0-1.0].

Edit:

it seems that doing it like `param = param * 0.1` did the job!

Comment: Range of parameters and and by what scale it has to be reduced ?examples

Comment: Maybe the answer really is infinity, nan, etc....?

Comment: It would seem the whole point of programming is to deal with the values of variables that we don't know in advance and manipulate those unknowns, once they are known, in useful ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain the parameter does not approach the limits of the type in which it is stored, just multiply by a number less then 1 (make the number closer to zero):

```
new_val = old_val * 0.99;  # new_val is 99% of old_val
```

If the sign is important, the following code decreases the number by 1%:

```
new_val = old_val - abs(0.01 * old_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's say `a bit` for you is `5%`, then:

```
   def my_func(parameter):
       return parameter - (0.05 * parameter)
```

Comment: or even just `return parameter * 0.95`, the subtraction seems entirely superfluous.